# How parity of Stirling numbers of second kind reduced to a simple proposition i.e $S(n,k) = \lnot ((n - k) \land ((k - 1) / 2))$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Recently I have been reading about [Parity of Stirling Numbers of 2nd Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Parity) and I am not able to understand how the parity of these numbers can be calculated by using a simple propositional logic:
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red] { 
S(n,k) =\;\lnot ((n - k)\; \land ((k - 1) / 2))
}$$ 
where $n$ is size of the set, and $k$ is number of sub-sets.

```
if not ((n - m) & ((m - 1) >> 1)):
    print("1")
else:
    print("0")
```

Refer the below definition as a refresher for Stirling Number of Second Kind:

> In mathematics, particularly in combinatorics, a Stirling number of
>   the second kind (or Stirling partition number) is the number of ways
>   to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets and is
>   denoted by $$S(n,k)\; \text{or} \;{\{^n_k\}}$$.

I was solving a programming problem [Binary Stirling Numbers](https://www.spoj.com/problems/BINSTIRL/) and end-up on the above article.

Things which I have tried to solve the problem was:
As the recursive formula is already given, I tried an approach based on dynamic programming and it gave me Time Limit Exceeded, and then I thought of finding some patterns.
So, I plotted Stirling Numbers of Second Kind without taking$\pmod 2$ till $n = 6$, here is what I got:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 15 & 25 & 10 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 31 & 90 & 65 & 15 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

and when I plotted the same matrix by taking each cell value$\pmod 2$, I got the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Both the above matrices basically shows the Stirling number of second kind till $n = 6$ for $k <= n$ where n = rows, k = columns.
Any grid $(i,j)$ in the above matrix tells you the value of $S(i,j)$.

For the binary matrix, I wrote the decimal representation of every row starting from the first, and I got the following sequence:
$$1,3,7,13,29,55,115,209,465,883,1847, \dots$$

The sequence didn't make any sense at first but when I searched for the sequence in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C7%2C13%2C29%2C55%2C115%2C209%2C465%2C883%2C1847%2C&language=english&go=Search), I got a hit and the sequence is a [A bisection of  Diagonals of Pascal's triangle mod 2 interpreted as binary numbers](https://oeis.org/A260022/list).

But that was the dead-end, because even if I use this approach,the complexity of the algorithm will be more than the actual recursive equation of Stirling Number of second kind.
$$
S(n,k) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n = 0$, $k = 0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $n \gt 0$, $k = 0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $n = 0$, $k \gt 0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $n \lt k$} \\[2ex]
k \times S(n - 1,k) + S(n - 1,k - 1), & \text{if $n \geq k$}
\end{cases}$$

So, even though there is a direct propositional formula on Wikipedia for finding the parity of Stirling numbers of second kind, I am not able to understand how can I arrive at that formula.

Comment: I suspect you can easily prove the parity formula through the recursive equation you've cited.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I am not able to do it. Can you tell?